# How to wait until the embedded ajax call is completed when injecting my script?

Tags: ajax, jquery, google-chrome-extension

It's Google Chrome extension development. I'm using content script to inject into webpages. However some webpages have their own ajax scripts that change the content dynamically. How do I wait until such scripts are completed, since before their completion my script cannot obtain the correct content?

For example,

1- on Google search result page,

2- I want to append "text" to title of every search result item, which could be easily done by calling,

```
$('h3').append("text");
```

3- then listen to the search query change, done by

```
$('input[name="q"]').change( function(eventObj){
    console.log("query changed");
    // DOESN'T work
    $('h3').append("text");
});
```

The last line doesn't work *probably* because at the time it's executed the page is still refreshing and `$('h3')` is not available. Google uses ajax to refresh the search result when the query is changed on the page.

So the question is how to capture this change and *still* be able to append "text" every time successfully?

**EDIT:**

Have tried and didn't work either:

```
$('h3[class="r"]').delay(1000).append("text");
```

and using `.delay()` is not really preferred.

**EDIT:**

`.delay()` is simply not designed to solve *pause* the execution of scripts other than UI effects. An workaround is

```
$('input[name="q"]').change(function(eventObj) {    
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('h3[class="r"]').append(" text");
    }, 1000);
});
```

But as I argued before, `setTimeout()` is connection-speed dependent, not preferred because I have to manually balance the time of waiting and the speed of response (of my script).

Although this post is down-voted for god-knows-why I'll still be waiting for an elegant answer.

Comment: in that code you delay 1 sec AFTER you append things. Change the order.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with jQuery 1.7+ (or with older version using "live" or "delegate")

```
$('form').on( "change", 'input[name="q"]', function(eventObj){
    console.log("query changed");
    $('h3').append("text");
});
```

If `form` is another element, change it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it doesn't work since after 'change' event the webpage uses ajax to refresh its content and 'h3' is only available after the refresh is completed.

Comment: This is actually event delegation, so whenever a new `input[name="q"]` is added to the `form`, it will delegate the given event to `input[name="q"]` no matter if this is AJAX or not since the event sits on the form. If the form is also dynamicly added, you need to attach it somewhere else for it to work. Check http://api.jquery.com/on/ section "Direct and delegated events"

Comment: I'm afraid you still don't get the question. Fire a `change()` is not the problem. Your code is basically the same as 2- in the post since `input[name="q"]` is always available thus can be accessed directly (and listen to `change()`). It's `h3` cannot be accessed after `change()` is fired because you have to wait until the content is constructed.